# How to linearly remap variable in representation of a family of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, soft-question

Power series expansions usually work quite nicely within $t\in[-1,1]$ due to multiplication remaining in this interval.

Say we want to move some interval of interest $[a,b] \to [-1,1]$.

How can we algebraically manipulate a differential equation to squeeze a function into this area?

Some simple ones $f''(x) + f(x) = 0$ has famous solutions sin and cos. But these have long period, we would like to squeeze  $[-\pi N,\pi N] \to [-1,1]$ so that we will be able to numerically calculate at least a few periods instead of just a fraction of a period.

The family of differential equations I want to consider are the same as in this previous question

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} h_k(t)\cdot f^{(k)}(t) + g(t) = 0$$
Where $h_k(t)$s have some truncated power series expansion.
$$h_k(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{M} c_kt^k$$
We can easily verify we will quickly get numerical issues when $M$ large and $|t|\gg1$.

So now to the question, given a known function expressed this way, how can we alter the $h_k(t)$s in order for the new solution to be linearly scaled $[a,b] \to [-1,1]$?

Comment: Am I understanding the question correctly in saying that you want to do this in order to allow one to numerically approximate the solution to the differential equation more easily by considering its Taylor expansion?

Comment: @YiFan yes, for higher exponents in Taylor series it can usually be difficult to calculate values far from 0 as a number bigger than 1 raised to a large power can get outside of range of numbers we can represent.

Comment: Although Taylor series are expanded specifically around one point, and it's not for sure the way we would always want to do it. But it's the same kind of polynomial anyways.